# Secure way to store sensitive API details of users (localStorage or database?)

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, security, electron

I am playing around with the idea of creating a website for cryptocurrencies, where a user can sign up on my website, enter his API details for one of the exchange markets that I will support, which allows him to trade on that exchange, but using my “more user friendly” web interface.

My main goal is to create a more user friendly interface than what most exchange websites offer. I am not hooking directly into any cryptocurrencies or wallets, all I do is use the API of existing exchange markets, relay the information to my website, where I have a more user friendly interface.

Since this is a very sensitive subject in regards to security, I am trying to figure out, what the best way would be to store the API details of the users.
In general I don’t like the idea of storing the API details on my database server, nor on my server in general. The thought of having my website hacked and all the API details being exposed is terrifying. Of course each exchange website that supports APIs has their own security built in, such as API sessions with 2FA, IP restrictions, weekly generations of new API secret keys, daily trading limits via API, and not allowing withdrawals of wallets via API. But damage can still be done if those API details get stolen.

I would prefer if there would be a way where I would not need to store the API details on my server at all, but rather have the user save them locally on his PC. That way he is in charge of keeping the API details secure.

This thought brought me then to the idea of creating a desktop app using electron (https://electron.atom.io/). That way I can still create the website the way I want, but it’s wrapped into electron, so it always run locally. Before I pursue this idea, I would like to keep investigating my previous idea of a regular website, as I prefer to have my website cloud based, SaaS, to prevent piracy.

So I wonder, storing API details of a user, without saving them on the server, what other options would I have?
Cookies? Probably not secure.
What about localStorage? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API

Are there other options or am I too paranoid about this? Is it generally accepted to store sensitive API details on a database server along with the rest of the users details?

Comment: Since you are using Electron, you might be able to write a wrapper around some encrypting methods provided by the base OS such as [`CryptProtectData `](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380261%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) on Windows. If you are paranoid that these sensitive data will get stolen by some other programs, encrypt it with the wrapper you wrote and store it in local storage or some other forms of storage. Also try [InfoSecurity.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/) for better advices on security.

Answer (score 1):

I think saving data in to users computers is wrong way, because  when you will save user's personal data in to your server, you will be able to control security of your server, when  it will be saved on user compputer the security of your server will be depended from users. Today we know many methods how to deceve users and I think, that the programmers  must take care of his users. when you will save data in server db you can switch many methods, like email verification or verification by phone you can send  message with some verification code, switch ssl service, also you can avoid on sql injection using a modern framework like Laravel or Yii 2,  in any case if you will save  user data in you server the security of your application will be depended of you.
if you will save  user data  in local computer, today hackers uses many methods to steal users cookies or methods to get a controll on pc, for example  you can read this post
https://krebsonsecurity.com/2011/09/right-to-left-override-aids-email-attacks/
today hackers using this method, creates an exe file which extension on first look is docx  or other some extension for example  pdf and so on ...
but in real it is an exe file and it is runnable, user can download it, and run... I think  you understood what can do hacker with users computers by this way, today so many viruses which even very professional users cant recognize.